# Adding a space into a certain string in python

Tags: python

I have data that looks like this:

```
SMITH,JOHN, additional data delimited by commas
JONES,TOMMY, additional data delimited by commas
WILLIAMS, BILLY, additional data delimited by commas
etc.
```

I need to make it look like this:

```
SMITH, JOHN, additional data delimited by commas
JONES, TOMMY, additional data delimited by commas
WILLIAMS, BILLY, additional data delimited by commas
etc.
```

Notice the extra space after the comma on the first two names.

I think I need to use a regex to make this happen, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried:

```
grantor = grantor.replace(r'[A-Z],[A-Z]', r'[A-Z], [A-Z]')
```

but it isn't happening for me. What have I missed? I only need to change the names where there is a text character, a comma, and a text character immediately next to each other. Other names in the list are right and don't need to be changed.

Comment: `str.replace(",",", ")`?

Comment: *"What have I missed?"* - at least two things: 1. `str.replace` (*don't* name your own variable `str`, by the way; you shadow the built-in) has nothing to do with regular expressions; and 2. that's not how you'd write a regex pattern and replacement to do this anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but if I use what you are suggesting, it would replace all the commas in the list (there is additional text after the names). I only need to replace the commas that are immediately preceded and proceeded by uppercase text characters.

Comment: Then I suggest you have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub and something like https://regex101.com/. You could o make the first and second names separate capturing groups (including the comma with the first, if you like) and use those groups in the replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does not use regular expressions. You would have to use the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for that.

But since you are just replacing a comma by a comma and a space, you don’t actually need regular expressions here:

```
s = '''SMITH,JOHN
JONES,TOMMY
etc.'''

s = s.replace(',', ', ')

print(s)
# SMITH, JOHN
# JONES, TOMMY
# etc.
```

> I only need to replace the commas that are immediately preceded and proceeded by uppercase text characters.

Then you might want to use regular expressions after all. You will have to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for this:

```
import re
s = 'FOO, SMITH,JOHN'

s = re.sub('([A-Z]),([A-Z])', r'\1, \2', s)
print(s)
# FOO, SMITH, JOHN
```

This uses references to put in those two characters around the comma. You can also use lookbehinds and lookaheads for this:

```
s = 'FOO, SMITH,JOHN'

s = re.sub('(?<=[A-Z]),(?=[A-Z])', ', ', s)
print(s)
# FOO, SMITH, JOHN
```

Comment: You knocked it out of the ballpark! Thanks so much!